# Debugging Thread blocked indefinitely in an MVar operation

Tags: ghc

A program compiled with GHC 8.2.1 ends with the following error message.

> Foo: thread blocked indefinitely in an MVar operation

Given it's reproducible locally, is there any information available at runtime to narrow down source of the problem?